# React get address from Google Maps ? #react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I am Junior React Developer. In my new project there is something like this. (marked with red rectangle) Is there any way to get address with this way ? User open Google Maps pin the location and address text shows up ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first save the lat and the lng : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-click-latlng

And after with GeoCoding convert the lat and the lng to an address : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview